# Counting dummy variable = 1 observations in a dataset for two specific years

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to count how many enterprise zones were designated in two specific years out of 8 total years. I first isolated the years with the following code:

```r
ez <- ezunem %>% select(3,7,8)
```

Then tried to count the enterprise zones that were in the select columns:

```r
ez %>% count(ez, sort=TRUE)
```

This didnt work. What is the best way to count `dummy variables = 1` out of two columns in R.

Edit: here is the output with dput(ez) command:

```r
structure(list(ez = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    d84 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), 
    d85 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-198L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

> So, basically I want my output to count the 1's for d84 and d85.

Comment: Just to clarify. `select(3,7,8)` selects the columns 3, 5 & 8. It does not select rows 3, 5 & 8.
Could you use `dput(df)` and paste the output into your question and let us know your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
ez %>% 
  group_by(ez) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(d84, d85), sum, .names="count_{.col}"))
```

```
   ez count_d84 count_d85
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     0        16        12
2     1         6        10
```